# How should a helicopter pilot react after V-belt breaking?

Tags: helicopter, emergency-procedures, failures

I have a question concerning the V-belts of the Robinson R22 (or R44) breaking in-flight. When they break, the rotor RPM will drop and the engine will tend to overspeed. (Is this actually correct?) What are the appropriate actions? I know that I need to flare to get rotor RPM back, but do I also need to close the throttle a bit to reduce engine RPM?

Comment: The engine going overspeed is less important than getting to the ground safely.

Comment: While this seems like a very valid question to me, my immediate (IANAP) thought is "sounds like someone should be doing a more thorough pre-flight inspection"!

Comment: @FreeMan My question did not start with "I feel like skipping pre-flight so...". And thinking that after a thorough inspection you're completely safe might just be as unsafe as not checking.

Comment: What triggered my question is that I was reading some V-belt incident/accidents reports and many of them stated that the pilot saw, next to the rotor RPM dropping, the engine RPM at the top of the red line. So I was wondering what I should do for what concerns the engine, apart from making sure that I don't fall like a brick.

Comment: Not an answer but if you re sure that the belt is gone (and not something else), you could shut down the engine. Side benefit is that this will focus the pilot's attention only to landing.. (not a serious recommendation!)

Comment: sorry, @10a - that wasn't intended to be an attack on you! I do understand that even after an inspection things can fail.

Comment: @FreeMan No worries, my answer sounded more defensive as intended ;)

Comment: @GürkanÇetin Do you mean fully closing the throttle? Is it best to disable the governor too then? And what if I didn't lose the belt completely?

Comment: @10a how could you "not lose the belt completely"? Once it fails such that there is a disconnected rotor and engine speed there is no torque transfer from engine to rotor

Comment: @ratchetfreak I mean if one is gone and the second is too stretched out or both are stretched so that they/it slip/s a bit. The rotor is still driven but not enough to maintain RPM. Or is that not a possible situation? But my main question was if both are gone.

Comment: I had meant turning off the engine completely (not serious but technically to protect the engine over speed this would work).

Comment: Most likely immediately initiate an autorotate descent and make ready for an off field landing, thence shut down and secure the engine.

Answer (score 2):

A number of R22 accident reports indicate that the rotor RPM drops and the engine will tend to overspeed in case of 'V' belt failure. From the Australian Transport Safety Bureau report [Reliability of the Robinson R22 helicopter belt drive system](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/4120236/ai-2009-038_final.pdf):

> **NTSB occurrence report: LAX92LA034**
>
> ... pilot reported that the engine RPM indicator suddenly pegged at the top of the gauge and the rotor RPM began rapidly decreasing. ... Examination ... revealed that the forward v-belt was split longitudinally and displaced from the transmission pulleys. The rear belt was found off the engine and transmission pulleys.
>
> **CAA occurrence report: 99/23**
>
> ... there was a bang and the engine ‘revved up’, but power to the main rotor was lost. The power loss to the main rotors was due to broken v-belts.
>
> **NTSB occurrence report: NYC08LA043**
>
> ... , the engine’s RPM sharply  increased and the main rotor RPM alarm sounded. Post-accident examination of the helicopter drive system revealed that the v-belts had rolled off the sheaves
>
> **NTSB occurrence report: N993KC**
>
> The pilot ... heard a loud ‘bang’. The pilot ... observed the engine RPM was excessively high, the rotor RPM was below 80 percent and the low rotor
> RPM warning horn was sounding. The on-scene investigation noted that one of the v-belts to the main rotor drive system had separated,  which caused the other belt to slip off the upper spindle.

In case of suspected belt failure, the pilot is expected to try and make a power on landing while prepared for an autorotative one. From the [R-22 Flight Manual](http://www.anythingaboutaviation.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Robinson-R22-Flight-Manual.pdf):

> ... if the clutch light flickers or stays on for a longer time than usual,  it can indicate a belt or bearing failure in the vee-belt  drive. If that occurs, immediately pull the  CLUTCH  circuit breaker. Select the closest  safe landing  site and make  a normal power-on landing. Be prepared  to  enter autorotation should failure of the drive system occur. The smell of burning rubber may also indicate an impending belt failure.

Note that there is no talk about the throttle. Though the R22 has two V belts, it is not designed to fly with a single one (though there seems to be some instances of that). My guess is that it is better for the pilot not to tinker with the throttle for two reasons- if the problem is somewhere else, reducing the rpm would have adverse effects and if the belt is indeed gone, it would be better for the pilot to concentrate on saving the people first and the engine later.